# Stuck in Chainlink VRF Randomness Function Implementation

Tags: remix, polygon, vrf

[URGENT QUESTION]
I am trying to get a random number in my contract. I have imported both VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol and VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol and inherited them in my contract.

I am using the following code:

```
contract NFTES_Drop is ERC1155, VRFConsumerBaseV2, Ownable {

    //VRF----------------
  VRFCoordinatorV2Interface COORDINATOR;

  // Your subscription ID.
  uint64 s_subscriptionId;

  // Rinkeby coordinator. For other networks,
  // see https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/#configurations
  address vrfCoordinator = 0xAE975071Be8F8eE67addBC1A82488F1C24858067;

  // The gas lane to use, which specifies the maximum gas price to bump to.
  // For a list of available gas lanes on each network,
  // see https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/#configurations
  bytes32 keyHash = 0xd729dc84e21ae57ffb6be0053bf2b0668aa2aaf300a2a7b2ddf7dc0bb6e875a8;

  // Depends on the number of requested values that you want sent to the
  // fulfillRandomWords() function. Storing each word costs about 20,000 gas,
  // so 100,000 is a safe default for this example contract. Test and adjust
  // this limit based on the network that you select, the size of the request,
  // and the processing of the callback request in the fulfillRandomWords()
  // function.
  uint32 callbackGasLimit = 100000;

  // The default is 3, but you can set this higher.
  uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;

  // For this example, retrieve 2 random values in one request.
  // Cannot exceed VRFCoordinatorV2.MAX_NUM_WORDS.
  uint32 numWords =  2;
constructor(uint64 subscriptionId) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinator) ERC1155("") {
    COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinator);
    s_owner = msg.sender;
    s_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
    Owner = payable(msg.sender);
}
```

Apart from other logic,

Here is my  requestRandomWords function

```
 function requestRandomWords() internal returns (uint256) {
    uint256 requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
        keyHash,
        s_subscriptionId,
        requestConfirmations,
        callbackGasLimit,
        numWords
    );
 // Return the requestId to the requester.
    return requestId;
    }
```

And here is how I am calling the function:

```
 uint256 index = requestRandomWords();
```

the compiler shows no bugs. but when I call the function within my cintract I get the following error:

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": 3, "message": "execution reverted: Not Enough Balance", "data": "0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000124e6f7420456e6f7567682042616c616e63650000000000000000000000000000" }

Anyone please help!

Comment: Do you have enough balance on your wallet because you are getting the following error: *"message": "execution reverted: Not Enough Balance"*

Comment: Yes I have enough balance